# PHP changes the type of $a from integer to object. Why?

Tags: php

```
<?php
$a = 3;
echo 'typeof $a is : ' . gettype($a) . "\n"; // integer

$b = &$a;
echo 'typeof  $b es : ' . gettype($b) . "\n"; // integer

$c = new stdClass;
$c->name = "charles";

$b = $c;
$b->name = "bill";

echo '$c->name : ' . $c->name . "\n";
echo 'typeof $b es : ' . gettype($b) . "\n";


echo 'typeof $a is : ' . gettype($a) . "\n"; // object
echo 'The value of $a is : ' . $a->name; // bill
?>
```

Output:

```
typeof $a is : integer
typeof  $b is : integer
$c->name : bill
typeof  $b is : object
typeof $a is : object
The value of $a is : bill
```

Comment: Can you post the output of your code?

Comment: Your code has a syntax error.

Comment: Output here: http://ideone.com/R2Ii6

Comment: Do you understand the situation now?

Answer (score 3):

It's because you're setting $b to share the same memory address as $a.  So when you change $b, $a gets changed as well.

Set `$b = $a` instead of `$b = &$a` if the results are undesirable.

Comment: Output of my code is : typeof $a is : integer

typeof $b is : integer

$c->name :bill

typeof $b is : object

typeof $a is : object

The value of $a is : bill

Comment: No, you paste your output in your question and format it correctly. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 3):

- `$b` is a [reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to `$a`.
- You make `$b` equal to `$c`, an object.
- That means `$b` is now an object...
- ...and since `$b` is just a reference to `$a`, `$a` is an object too.

Answer (score 1):

You tell `$b` to be a reference to `$a`:

```
$b = &$a;
```

Then you tell `$b` to refer to the object that is referred to by `$c`:

```
$b = $c;
```

Since `$b` and `$a` are "linked" to the same value, both are the same reference to the same object, and `$a` loses its integer value.

You now have two distinct references to a single `stdClass` object: one belongs to `$c`, which is obtained by creating the object and assigning it. The other is created by assigning the reference of `$c`, *by value* to `$b`, so it's copied. This is then shared by linking `$b` and `$a` together (assigning by reference).

Comment: Thanks BoltClock. I got it now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the php documentation on references, must read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Because `a` is a reference (**not** a copy - thanks Tomalak) of `b`, because you use the `&`, so whenever `b` changes `a` will change also. So when later on you make `b=c` (which currently `c` is an object) `b` becomes an object and thus `a` (the reference of `b`) becomes one too.

Comment: -1: `a` is **not** a copy of `b`. `b` is a reference to `a`: they are the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Because `$b = &$a` refer to `$a`, so `$b` and `$a` are *the same thing*, and any references to either are interchangeable.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem centers around creating this reference:

```
$b = &$a;
```

When you afterwards assign an object to `$b` it will be inherited by `$a`. [The assignment does not overwrite the reference.](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.whatdo.php#language.references.whatdo.assign) Instead $b is a name alias for $a's content, so all changes that you apply to $b will actually show up in $a instead. $b only retains the reference, not the properties.

Comment: Yes Mario. It's just a little confusing at times.